Finding two 2-hop neighborhood graph?
I have nodes of interest and was able to extract a subgraph (code below) but I believe the NetworkX subgraph() or induced_subgraph() only extracts 1-hop neighborhood of the nodes.
## Extract subgraph using nodes of interest (list)
G_S = induced_subgraph(G, S) # S is nodes of interest (list)

I looked at Ego Graph but it only extracts graphs on a single node.
How can I extract a 2 or 3-hop (or even beyond) subgraph? If NetworkX can't be used does graph-tool have a function where I can extract a k-hop subgraph?
Attempt on 2-hop subgraph:
def extend_subgraph(G, S):
    # Start with the original set of nodes of interest
    extended_nodes = set(S)
    
    # Loop over each node in the current subgraph
    for node in S:
        # Get 1-hop neighbors of this node
        one_hop = set(nx.neighbors(G, node))
        
        # For each 1-hop neighbor, get its 1-hop neighbors
        for neighbor in one_hop:
            if neighbor not in extended_nodes:
                extended_nodes.add(neighbor)
                neighbors_of_neighbor = set(nx.neighbors(G, neighbor))
                
                # Add the 1-hop neighbors of the neighbor if they haven't been seen
                extended_nodes.update(neighbors_of_neighbor - extended_nodes)

    # Create a new subgraph with the extended set of nodes
    G_extended_subgraph = G.subgraph(extended_nodes)
    
    return G_extended_subgraph

G2 = extend_subgraph(G, S)


Loop over the 1-hop neighbours and add THEIR 1-hop neighbors if they have not been seen yet.

In other words, the induced subgraph using G_S as the nodes of interest.

For hops larger than 2, bfs_tree has a depth_limit parameter. Create a dummy source node connected to all of the nodes of interest and increase the depth by 1.

@ravenspoint updated the post with my attempt at the code. Is that how it should be?

@beaker , and ravenpoint, updated the post with my attempt at the code. Not sure if I wrote it correctly but any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Asking random strangers on the internet their opinion of your code is a rarely recommended test process.  Test the output - is it correct?

If the format is flexible, you can use dgl to represent your graph and use the khop_out_subgraph function to extract your desired subgraph of k hops. Then use the method to_networkx to convert back to networkx if necessary.
